# How to know when a particular button is clicked in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, listener

I'm making a function that displays a modal, and the modal has two buttons. I want this function to wait until one of the two buttons has been clicked, and return a value that corresponds to which button is clicked.

Here's a sample code that I came up with:

```
function myFunc()
{
  var val=0;
  buttonA = document.getElementById('buttonA');
  buttonB = document.getElementById('buttonB');
  buttonA.onclick = function(){
    //do something
    val = 1;
  }
  buttonB.onclick = function(){
    //do something
    val = 2;
  }
  while(val == 0);
  return val;
}
```

The problem in this code is that the page becomes unresponsive because of the infinite loop, hence it isn't possible to change the value of `val` once initialised.

To be more precise, I want the main thread (on which myFunc is being implemented) to sleep until one of the other two threads (each of buttonA and buttonB) is clicked.

Is there some other work-around for this ? Please answer in Javascript only (no jQuery). Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason not to just return 1 or 2 from your onclick handlers?

Comment: Your infinite loop is a bad design. Your thread will stay stuck. You need to call the function you want to execute on click from the function link to the button.

Comment: @AxelH I know the infinite loop is a bad design, and it doesn't work, which is why I posted the question here :P
I just wrote that so as to explain what I want to achieve. I dont want the function to end unless one of the buttons is clicked.

Comment: But you can't wait ... if you wait, you will block everything ... The thread need to be release. You can set a flag `modal` to `true` to block some action by checking the flag value but this can be ...

Comment: Let's back up, why do you want to wait for those two input ? what other choice the user have ?

Comment: @AxelH No other choice. Check the comment on Ceshion's answer for explaination. :P

Comment: Ok, I will try to find a code I did to wait for an async result ... but no idea where I put this one. Basicly, it was not a while loop but a `setTimeout` to check the value every 250ms, if the value was null ( in your case 0) I wait more, if not, I execute the callback method. But you CAN'T wait to return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
function myFunc()
{
  buttonA = document.getElementById('buttonA');
  buttonB = document.getElementById('buttonB');
  buttonA.onclick = function(){
    //do something
    differentFunc(1)
  }
  buttonB.onclick = function(){
    //do something
    differentFunc(2)
  }
}
```

This is a different way to make the function more versatile (edited per your comment):

```
function myFunc(callback)
{
  buttonA = document.getElementById('buttonA');
  buttonB = document.getElementById('buttonB');
  buttonA.onclick = function(){
    //do something
    callback(1)
  }
  buttonB.onclick = function(){
    //do something
    callback(2)
  }
}
```

and call it like

```
myFunc(function(result) {
    // do stuff with result
    }
```

Javascript is naturally single-threaded. Any code that waits infinitely like that will cause a hangup and disallow input. There are ways to write async functions, namely using Promises like I did for a minute there, but it's generally easier to make your code work synchronously.

Comment: Better, but please explain why it is better like this :)

Comment: I could do that, but the thing is that I made this function so as to reuse it every time whenever I need confirmation for some task.
Say, whenever I have to delete/add/edit some object, I call this function to ask for confirmation : it displays a modal with the message "Are you sure?" and the two buttons are "Yes" or "No".
Depending on from where `myFunc` is being called, there'll be different codes to implement. I just need to know whether "Yes" was clicked or "No".

Comment: Thanks a lot :D
This one works just fine. I don't think it's possible to have an elegant code for what I was aiming at (pausing the main thread until other two responded). But this does the job too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the OP's purpose is to create a modal with 2 choices like a [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)? But for some reason `confirm()` isn't suitable? So a value on each button and it waits for user interaction? Unless I'm missing something fairly important, I have made a dynamically generated modal (no manual markup) that has 2 buttons. The purpose and result elude me so I left it with one event listener and a function with a simple ternary condition to which the alerts can be replaced by appropriate statements or expression at OP's discretion.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .modal {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background:transparent;
    }
    .ui {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      display: table-cell;
      border: 3px ridge grey;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    button {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var modal = document.createElement('div');
    var ui = document.createElement('div');
    var on = document.createElement('button');
    var off = document.createElement('button');
    modal.className = 'modal';
    ui.className = 'ui';
    on.id = 'on';
    on.textContent = 'On';
    off.id = 'off';
    off.textContent = 'Off';
    frag.appendChild(modal);
    modal.appendChild(ui);
    ui.appendChild(on);
    ui.appendChild(off);
    ui.addEventListener('click', status, false);

    function status(e) {
      var tgt = e.target.id;
      tgt === 'on' ? alert('ON!') : alert('OFF!');
    }
    document.body.appendChild(frag);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```